# Can't configure nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running php+nginx api inside docker container. It is available on port 8080. I trying to add nginx reverse proxy to open api on address api.versite.online and frontend project on versite.online.

I installed nginx on server, added `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.versite.online` config (also added symlink to sites-enabled directory), tested config with `nginx -t`, restarted nginx service with `systemctl reload nginx`, but it had no effect. api.versite.online:8080 and versite.online:8080 makes request to docker container, looks like top level nginx are ignored.
Nginx access log is empty.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.versite.online config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.versite.online;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/api.versite.access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i forgot to add a firewall rule with `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'`